# Uploading file with Spring RestTemplate to LogicalDOC

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, resttemplate, multipart

I'am trynig to upload file to [LogicalDOC DMS](https://docs.logicaldoc.com/resources/wsdoc/rest/index.html?version=8.1.0#!/document/upload) but I'am getting error 500. Exception from theirs logs is (I think they are using `apache jax rs`)

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't determine the boundary from the message!
```

I have configured `RestTemplate` like this

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    return mapper;
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper());
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));

    ResourceHttpMessageConverter resourceHttpMessageConverter = new ResourceHttpMessageConverter();

    ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
    byteArrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG,
            MediaType.IMAGE_GIF,
            MediaType.IMAGE_PNG,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
            MediaType.TEXT_XML,
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN,
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML
    ));

    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    formHttpMessageConverter.setPartConverters(Arrays.asList(
            resourceHttpMessageConverter,
            byteArrayHttpMessageConverter
    ));

    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(
            mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter,
            formHttpMessageConverter,
            resourceHttpMessageConverter,
            byteArrayHttpMessageConverter
    ));
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(responseErrorHandler());

    return restTemplate;
}
```

And created `service`

```
public DocumentDto upload(Long folderId, String fileName, byte[] file, Long documentId) {
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

    params.add("folderId", folderId);
    params.add("filename", fileName);
    params.add("filedata", file);

    if (Objects.nonNull(documentId)) {
        params.add("docId", documentId);
    }

    return client.upload("/document/upload", params, DocumentDto.class);
}
```

And rest `client`

```
public <T> T upload(String path, MultiValueMap<String, Object> body, Class<T> clazz) throws RestClientException {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    return restTemplate.exchange(getUrl(path), HttpMethod.POST, entity, clazz).getBody();
}
```

And finally `test` ...service call

```
service.upload(FOLDER_ID, "application.yml", getDocument(), null);

private byte[] getDocument() {
    byte[] file = new byte[]{};
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:application.yml");
    try {
        file = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

So can you please help me. I suspect that I'am not sending the right representation info of attached file. Did anyone have similar problem with sending file with Spring `RestTemplate`. I also try with `Resource` class instead of `byte[]` but I get the same error.